# Should I wait till the completion of all possible experiments?

Tags: publications, phd, machine-learning

I am aware that this question can be answered in different ways based on the domain of research under consideration. So, you can confine the answer to the domain of machine learning.

Suppose I am working on a technique in a particular application using a model and get success. And there is a certain hope that the model can further be improved drastically. I don't want to put any of my papers on any pre-print.

In this context, I got a dilemma on the question "**should I wait till complete experimentation for publishing or should I announce the success first and then improve?**"

Pros and cons for waiting:

Pros:

1. I can write a full-fledged research paper.
2. No need of doing an incremental paper i.e., writing multiple small papers.

Cons:

1. I cannot announce the results quickly.
2. I cannot use my results for my academic requirements if someone publishes the same early.
3. Others may treat it as a salami-slicing publication.

Note: Complete experimentation or full-fledged refers to developing a fine-tuned model. But the experimentation showing the domination of the (model based on) technique is already established.

Answer (score 1):

The best people to comment on this are your colleagues or your advisor(if any).
A paper gets published in a reputed journal only when it has publishable material. So unless and until you show your work to your peers(or your coauthors), you are not sure if the output of the experiment is publishable or not. Also it depends on where you would like to publish your paper. If you would like to publish your paper in a high IF journal, and there is significant room for improvement of your results, there is a high chance that the reviewers may reject your paper.

I would advise you to put your work online from where it will show that you were the first to publish it. Then work hard and improve the results and then publish an excellent research paper in a very good journal.
I say so because since you have developed the ideas first, it would be far more easier for you to develop the model as your peers will have to understand the work first and it will surely take time.
During this period you can build on your idea and produce some excellent publishable results.